# Scroll ListView when user drag&drops an item

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, drag-and-drop

I have a ListView `mRecipeListView` that contains a number of items.

Inside the `listViewAdapter`, when it generates views for the items to display, I add an `onLongClickListener` that starts a drag operation:

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
  ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
  View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
  view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
  // Highlight dragged view.
  view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.app_color_accent));
  view.invalidate();
}
```

The same view also gets an `onDragListener` so that each view is a valid drop target. The goal is of course to enable re-ordering of the views by drag and drop:

```
view.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent dragEvent) {
  switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {
    // ...
    // re-ordering works just fine
    // ...
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:                                   
      // y-coord of touch event inside the touched view (so between 0 and view.getBottom())
      float y = dragEvent.getY();
      // y-coord of top border of the view inside the current viewport.
      int viewTop = view.getTop();
      // y-coord that is still visible of the list view.
      int listBottom = mRecipeListView.getBottom(),
      listTop = mRecipeListView.getTop();

      // actual touch position on screen > bottom with 200px margin
      if (y + viewTop > listBottom - 200) {
        mRecipeListView.smoothScrollBy(100, 25);
        View child = mRecipeListView.getChildAt(mRecipeListView.getChildCount() - 1);
        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      } else if (y + viewTop < listTop + 200) {
        mRecipeListView.smoothScrollBy(-100, 25);
        View child = mRecipeListView.getChildAt(0);  
        child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      }
      return true;
  }
}
```

So, in the case of `ACTION_DROP_LOCATION`, which fires if the drag is continued inside the bounding box of a valid drop target view, I check whether the drag is so close to the bottom or top that we need to scroll.

This works, but it has flaws:

Views are recycled when you scroll, or equivalently, not all views are always present. When the drag is started, only the currently visible views are asked whether they want to accept drops. As the list is scrolled down, new views are added which were not asked, and they are not valid drop targets. The workaround for this are these lines:

```
View child = mRecipeListView.getChildAt(mRecipeListView.getChildCount() - 1);
child.setVisibility(View.GONE);
child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

for scrolling down. This means that the last child of the `listView` is acquired, its visibility changed to `GONE` and back, which forces it to register as a valid drop target. Analog for scrolling up, but get the child at index `0` instead of the last one.

Another problem arises for this for which I could not find a solution yet:

1) I highlight the item that the user is dragging by changing its background color. When the user now scrolls down, that item's view is discarded. When the user scrolls back up, the view is recycled, but it is now a different view than before. The background is changed back to the default, and keeping a reference to the view does not work either, as an equality check will fail because the recycled view is not the same as the original view. So I don't know how to keep the background changed for this item's view.

2) Scrolling is bound to events that fire when the user is dragging inside the bounding box of a valid drop target. This forced me to keep the view visible that the user is dragging, because I need that view's bounding box to start the scrolling event when it was, for example, the top visible view. I would rather turn it invisible, but for that I would have to do scrolling outside of the drag event constraint.

3) For the same reason: When the user keeps the finger at the bottom of the list and there is room to scroll it will only keep scrolling if the finger keeps moving, as otherwise no new event is fired.

I tried to react to `onTouchEvents` but it seemed they are not handled during a drag operation.

Comment: This is a lot read and understand. Did you get the code from a tutorial or project? Would you like good samples I have found for ListView drag-and-drop?